# GPUImage wrong rotation of video

Tags: ios, avfoundation, gpuimage

I record video using `AVCaptureSession`. After seeing the recorded video file (from iTunes) it always has the correct rotation (landscape right and landscape left). However, when I show the video using `GPUImageView` and `GPUImageMovie`, it will be upside down for landscape left.

Any ideas would be extremely helpful!

**UPDATE**

Now I noticed that when I take a screenshot from the video using `AVAssetImageGenerator`, that is also upside down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it by setting the input rotation:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
{
    [currentFilter setInputRotation:kGPUImageRotate180 atIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: Did you managed to solve the issue with AVAssetImageGenerator too?

Comment: Yes:     if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        _generatedThumbNailView.transform = CGAffineTransformConcat(CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI), CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(568.0f, 320.0f));
    }

Comment: Where to set It Can you tel me??